# count number of 0 with floodfill algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, flood-fill

I wanted to count number of 0 and 1 from a 2d array with floodfill algorithm....But unfortunetly...it's showing the wrong result.

I have a matrix like this

```
0,1,1,0,1

1,0,1,1,0

1,0,1,1,0

1,0,1,1,0

1,0,1,1,0
```

It supposed to show number of 0 = 10 and 1 =15

but it showing number of 0 = 4 and 1 = 21

here is my code

```
int[][] input;
public static int[,] reult;
public static int count = 0,col,row;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path;
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        input = File.ReadLines(file.FileName)
                .Skip(0)
                .Select(l => l.Split(',')
                    .Select(n => int.Parse(n))
                    .ToArray())
                    .ToArray();

    }

    reult = JaggedToMultidimensional(input);

    int p = reult.GetLength(0); 
    int q = reult.GetLength(1); 
    row = p-1;
    col = q - 1;
    int one = p * q;
    int zero = apply(row, col);
    label1.Text = "" + zero;
    label2.Text = "" + (one - zero);

}

public T[,] JaggedToMultidimensional<T>(T[][] jaggedArray)
{
    int rows = jaggedArray.Length;
    int cols = jaggedArray.Max(subArray => subArray.Length);
    T[,] array = new T[rows, cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = jaggedArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    return array;
}

private static int apply(int x, int y)
{
    int currentColor = getValueAt(x, y);
    if (currentColor == 0)
    {
        visit(x, y);
        count++;

        if (x < row) apply(x + 1, y);
        if(y<col) apply(x, y + 1);
       if(x>0) apply(x - 1, y);
       if (y>0) apply(x, y - 1);
    }
    return count;
}

private static int getValueAt(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > row || y > col)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return reult[x,y];
    }
}

private static void visit(int x, int y)
{
    reult[x,y] = 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a flood fill, and as such it only visits adjacent cells that are within a given parameter (in this case, `currentColor == 0`). You start at the bottom right, and there are 4 0's that cell's group. Your algorithm is doing exactly what it should be doing, and you are just misinterpreting the result.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: Is your goal to use a flood fill or to count the 1's and 0's?

Comment: count 0and 1 using floodfill algorithm...its a college prjct...my supervisor just said this

Comment: You are asking how to traverse the entire matrix using a flood fill algorithm, but that's not what flood fill does. It only visits a particular area based on your criteria, so the only way it will visit the entire matrix is if your entire matrix is 0's. If your goal is simply to count the 0's, then simple iteration would be much simpler, but if you're insisting on using flood fill then you are using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: One thing you _can_ do is to iterate over the matrix and whenever you find a 0, use flood fill to count the 0's in that group. But like I said, using iteration alone would be much simpler and likely faster too.

Comment: I tried to tell my supervisor the same thing....but he keep insisting... now I'm kind of traped

Comment: but thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int zero = apply(row, col);
```

In your flood fill algorithm, you are only going in four direction and cover the area which match your criteria. And fortunately `[row,col]` index has `0` and it count all four 0 from `[row, col]`. Now think what if `apply(row,col)` have `1` on that `row, col` index.

To get this thing right, you need to loop through whole matrix and call `apply(i,j)` where ever you find an `array[i,j]==0`

Change this line

```
int zero = apply(row, col);
```

to

```
int zero = 0;
for(int i=0; i<=row; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<=col; j++)
   {
       if(array[i][j]==0)
       {
          count =0;
          zero+= apply(row, col);
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements you should change the search criteria to search for 0's and 1's.

What you need to do is to search within the rectangle so the border of the rectangle is limit for searching.

i.e.

```
int[] count = {0,0};

private static int apply(int x, int y)
{
    int currentColor = getValueAt(x, y);
    if (currentColor != -1)
    {
        visit(x, y);
        count[currentColor]++;

        if (x < row) apply(x + 1, y);
        if(y<col) apply(x, y + 1);
       if(x>0) apply(x - 1, y);
       if (y>0) apply(x, y - 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

and then change your visit function to set the cell to -1 instead to avoid visiting it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use linq if you want (I actually prefer):

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadLines(fileDialog.FileName);
                var splittedValues = lines.Where(l => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l)).Select(l => l.Split(',')).SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
                var valCount = splittedValues.GroupBy(s => s).Select(s => new { val = s.Key, count = s.Count() }).ToList();     
            }
```

It will give you following result:

> [0] { val= "0", count=10} [1] { val= "1", count=15}